# How to use the ICM_ReceiveDocumentIDs Event?

Tags: javascript, dojo, filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator, ibm-case-manager

I'm trying to display a list of documents with the ContentList widget inside the IBM Case Manager Builder.

To achieve that I'm wiring a Scriptadapter to the ContentList widget, with the ReceiveDocuments event. This should give me the possibility to send the data as a JSON object to the ContentList.

Unfortunatly the documentation is very unclear about what exaclty is expected inside of this JSON object.

[It states](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/case-manager/5.3.3?topic=SSCTJ4_5.3.3/com.ibm.casemgmt.development.doc/jsdoc/symbols/icm.pgwidget.contentlist.test.ContentListWrapper.html):
[image: Image of the offical IBM documentation]

What exactly is meant with

> values: array of dojo objs[...]

I haven't been able to find anything on 'Dojo Objects', 'dojo objs', 'ibm dojo objects' etc. even after extensive searching.

I've assumed they must mean a simple object but this doesn't work:

```
payload = {
"objectStoreNames" : ["MyObjectStore"],
"symbolicNames": ["DocumentTitle","CmAcmAssociatedCase", "DateLastModified", "LastModifier"],
"values": [{"versionSeries":"604B5175-0210-C88C-B5CE-C7CA75FD8A9A"}],
"externalColumns": [],
"version": "current"
};

return payload;
```

What does work is if I ignore the `values` completely and leave it as an empty array. Although then it just gives me a list of **every** document inside of the object store.

What exactly am I supposed to put inside of this array? Any examples would be grand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bashing my head into the wall for way to many times, I've found the solution! In this case the official IBM documentation has a typo.

> values: array of dojo objs, each has obj.versionSeries field contains vsID

should be

> values: array of dojo objs, each has obj.**V**ersionSeries field contains vsID

which makes the correct payload something like this:

```js
payload = {
"objectStoreNames" : ["MyObjectStore"],
"symbolicNames": ["DocumentTitle","CmAcmAssociatedCase", "DateLastModified", "LastModifier"],
"values": [{VersionSeries:"604B5175-0210-C88C-B5CE-C7CA75FD8A9A"}],
"externalColumns": []
};

return payload;
```

Important differences to the payload in the question:

- the 'v' in 'VersionsSeries' must be capital case
- there are no quotation marks around 'VersionSeries'